# What makes this context static? And what what to do?

Tags: java, static, scope

I've just started to learn java and I'm having some problem with static/non-static. The problem with my code is within the `actionlistener`. When I try to compile it, it says:

> non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context.

Am I right to think that a action performed is static? If so, how can I use a `actionlistener` to perform a method? (I am well aware that I could just put the text in my code, into the `actionlistener`. But if I had different circumstances...)

```
 public class But extends JFrame{
    public void test(){
        //A method
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}

class TestListener implements ActionListener{
    public TestListener(){}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        But.test(); 
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`test()` in `But` is an instance method (non-static) but you are trying to access it like it's static.

Try

```
class TestListener implements ActionListener{
    private But but = new But();
    public TestListener(){}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        but.test(); 
}}
```

or if you intend to make `test()`, change it's signature to

```
public static void test(){
```

Comment: While that will compile, that's probably not going to call the instance of `But` that the OP intends.

Answer (score 1):

Your `TestListener` needs to know which button to call the `.test()` method on. So try:

```
class TestListener implements ActionListener {
    private final But but;
    public TestListener(But b) {
        but = b; // save the instance of But that we want to call
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        but.test(); 
    }
}
```

This changes the `TestListener` constructor to take an instance of a `But` and stores it away internally in the `but` field. Then, when the action is performed, the `.test()` method can be called.

You will need to modify the call to the `TestListener` constructor appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
But.test();
```

You need to create an instance of the "But" class. The way you're calling it here is as if it's a static (class) method, as opposed to a non-static (instance) method.

Maybe just a typo.